# Python + Selenium - Select Drop Down Option using Stored Variable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have written a python selenium script that selects a state value from a drop down. The HTML for the drop down element is copied below:

```
<div class="hQSHyh4QFG0Xh0d-6pxTF" tabindex="0" style="height: 238px; display: none;">
<div class="SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3 option-0 al-option">AL</div>
<div class="SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3 option-1 ak-option">AK</div>
<div class="SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3 option-2 as-option">AS</div>
<div class="SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3 option-3 az-option">AZ</div>
<div class="SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3 option-4 ar-option">AR</div>
<div class="SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3 option-5 ca-option">CA</div>
<div class="SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3 option-59 um-option">UM</div>
</div>
```

Problem: the automation script locates the same state value ("CA") using a hard-coded xpath statement (See code snippet from script below). Instead, I would like to select the state value using a stored variable called "state".

```
state_selection = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[6]")
state_selection.click()
```

Additional Notes: I have tried using other methods to locate the state value (see below) but, so far, I have only been successful using the hard-coded xpath above.

I also tried to locate the drop down element using the Selenium Select Method but I got messages telling me that "Select only works on <select> elements, not on 'div' "

driver.findElement(by.xpath("//select[@SD_7vnwWhO0KG80czzPb3='']/option[@value='CA']")).click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select required option by its text content:

```
state = "CA"
state_selection = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='%s']" % state)
state_selection.click()
```

Comment: Hi Andersson - Your code works (and is much cleaner than having the hard-coded xpath). However, is it possible to select the state value based on a variable?